# What is a good dedicated server for managing magento store with 500+stores and 1000 products?

Tags: magento-1.8, server-setup

I am planning to build a magento installation which will have like 100 multisites at first and then within the next 3 to 5 of months it will reach around 500 sites. Then probably 1000 stores with in an year. The number of products won't increase that much.

So basically I need a good set up on which I can set up this magento store!

Comment: Yea, so you need quite a lot of tricks to make this work and scale. Out of the box it won't work/load/run.

Comment: I would caution against so many store views, you will encounter performance problems - Is there a necessary business reason for so many stores?

Comment: Please say you have tested this, because only a handful of people have done it to that level (we know one of them) - due to the way Magento works internally you need enterprise grade hardware, architecture & some serious consultants. You need the high end of these http://www.nexcess.net/magento/enterprise-hosting or http://magento5x.vanquishhosting.com or http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/whitepaper/building-secure-scalable-and-highly-available-magento-stores-powered-by-rackspace

Comment: What about spanning the set up in different servers. Something like this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/how-to-use-different-hosting-account-for-one-magento-engine-with-several-webstor will it work?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a really big project! I am not quite sure if it is reasonable to build a Magento store with so many stores, because scaling may be a big problem here. Although it of course also depends on the number of visits you plan to have. Anyway, you should probably have a look at some form of cloud setup. Amazon Web Services may be a good idea here. You can build big setups with it which scale perfectly. As a reference, you should have a look at this [Magento SE question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/459/running-magento-in-an-aws-environment) and specifically at the [answer and resources of fbrnc](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/459/running-magento-in-an-aws-environment/461#461).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The number of visitors will be much less. I was thinking about having 2 dedis. One with SSD for the database and the other for the files and stuff. Anyway I will look into AWS. Thanks.